# Progress 4GL display to a variable

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm working with a codebase that has multiple display statements. So that all of the outputs line up, the various column numbers are also typed multiple times.

I would like to just use a variable for the column instead of searching for the line and then updating the column width. Something like:

```
def var i as int init 10.
disp "FOO" to i
     "BAR" to i + 5.
```

Comment: The question is very vague and it will be quite hard to provide valuable assistance unless you define the problem more accurately. Please can you provide a real example of the current code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you either want to have your frame defined dynamically and at the end so you can assess what the max size for that column is, or you want to define a static frame beforehand, it usually makes it respect the positions (but you won't be able to change it).
Now I was a little thrown off by your code because it has nothing to do with setting the column widths, looks like you're trying to write something different if you're on a specific part of the page. So you might want to look into a few printing functions such as FRAME-DOWN and FRAME-LINE.

Comment: Well the code is what I have to work with. Maybe I just used the wrong terminology. So it's not possible to do disp "FOO" to <variable>?

Comment: It is if you assign it to the variable prior to showing it. Or you can use display 'Foo' @ table.field if it's a field. Maybe I misunderstood what you initially asked. Is that what you would like to know?

Comment: Let me try this again.

I have this code I have to work with, it looks like this:

display "FOO" to 10.

This type of code is repeated all throughout the codebase. If I have to change the 10 to 12, I have to search throughout the codebase entire codebase for this type of line and change every 10 to 12. This sort of thing is prone to error. I want to replace the 10 with a variable so I only have to do the updating once on the variable. Is this not possible with display?

Comment: Have you looked into the @ I mentioned earlier? If you'd like to display something over a field name in a frame, that'd be the way to do it.